# primefaces - difference between p:panel and p:layout

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I started working on a large project that uses primefaces, which I am learning now.

I should update one of the pages that contains panels so that they are horizontally collapsible.

So I decided to change the panels for a border layout (since that layout already has the property collapsible)

But when I changed, the data no longer appear. On the server side I can still see the logs with all data that should be displayed.

I wonder what is the difference between the following codes:

1 - With panel

```
<h:panelGroup id="test" styleClass="test" layout="block">
    <p:panel id="configPanel" widgetVar="configPanelVar">  
        <ui:include src="/config.xhtml" />
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

2 - With layout

```
<p:layout id="test">
    <p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="true" collapsible="true">
        <ui:include src="/config.xhtml" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

config.xhtml just displays some names queried from the db.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was loading the data after

```
<ui:include src="/config.xhtml" />
```

So there were no data to be displayed :embarrassed